# How to store user statistics in the database (mysql) for different sections?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There is a uniform content, such as forum, news, articles etc. Content consists of a topic and its comments. User writes topics and comments, need to keep statistics on each user.

The first idea - to create a regular table users_stat, with fields user_id, forum_thread_count, forum_message_count, news_thread_count, news_message_count and so on. And when a new topic in a forum or a comment make

```
    UPDATE users_stat 
    SET forum_thread_count = forum_thread_count + 1 
    WHERE user_id = current_user_id.
```

But the problem is that there can add new sections, then we need to do alter table with statistics and it is not good.

There was also this idea. Create a table users_stat with fields user_id, content (varchar 50), counter. And when a new topic in a forum or a comment make

```
    UPDATE users_stat 
    SET counter = counter + 1 
    WHERE user_id = current_user_id 
    AND content = 'forum_thread'.
```

For the case of the first topic, when there are no records in the table users_stat for poster, make primary index on fields user_id and content and then saving statistics change to

```
    INSERT INTO users_stat (user_id, content, counter) 
    VALUES (current_user_id, 'forum_thread', 1 ) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = VALUES (counter + 1).
```

But it turns out that the "insert" works only once and then, every time you save , mysql will analyse of the entire table to search for duplicates. On large amounts will slow performance.

Can anyone throw more idea?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your 3rd way, but with "content" replaced by "content_id", which is a tiny integer field, referencing contents table. AND make a compound primary key of (user_id, content_id) [For better performance, make an auto increment id, and a unique(user_id, content_id)]
i.e.

```
contents(id, name): data example: (1, "Forum Thread")
user_stat(user_id int, content_id int, counter int): data example: (3, 1, 5)
```

Inserting and updating:

`INSERT INTO user_stat(user_id, content_id, counter) VALUES ($current_user_id, 1, 1 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = VALUES (counter + 1)`